# Dropdown displaying top and not in the bottom in Firefox

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am using Bootstrap 4 Cards and the framework select2. I have a basic dropdown select inside a card-body but this, display to the top in Firefox. However, works fine in Google Chrome. I cant understand why. How can I make to display bottom without set height?

```
   <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-row">
      <!--<label for="email" class="mr-sm-2">CIF:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="email">-->


      <select class="js-example-responsive js-example-basic-single" style="width: 50%">

        <optgroup label="...">
          <option>...</option>
          ...
      </select>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Thanks.